# Os produtos em minha tabela possuem uma ID, como vejo qual dessas ID ainda não foi usada em outra tabela?

Tags: mysql

Preciso mostrar os produtos que ainda não foram vendidos (não estiveram implicados em nenhuma venda), agrupados por Tipo e depois por Fabricante, e em ordem alfabética crescente por nome.

*Dei uma pesquisada antes de abrir o tópico, mas não cheguei em lugar nenhum, esse código foi um dos que eu vi em minhas pesquisas, porém só mais um que acabou me frustrando.*

Até onde cheguei:

```
select idproduto from vendas e where not exists
  (select * from produtos r where e.idproduto = r.id);
```

Saída:

```
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Estrutura das minhas tabelas:

```
mysql> select * from produtos;
+------+------------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| ID   | Nome                   | Fabricante | Quantidade | VlUnitario | Tipo       |
+------+------------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|    1 | Playstation 3          | Sony       |        100 |       2000 | Console    |
|    2 | Core 2 Duo 4GB RAM 500 | DELL       |        200 |       1900 | Notebook   |
|    3 | XBOX 360 120 GB        | Microsoft  |        350 |       1300 | Console    |
|    4 | GT-1620 QUAD BAND      | SAMSUNG    |        300 |        500 | Celular    |
|    5 | iPHONE 4 32 MB         | Apple      |         50 |       1500 | Smartphone |
|    6 | Playstation 2          | Sony       |        100 |        400 | Console    |
|    7 | Wii 120 MB             | Nintendo   |        250 |       1000 | Console    |
|    8 | S7                     | SAMSUNG    |        100 |       1500 | Smartphone |
|    9 | J7                     | SAMSUNG    |        300 |       1000 | Smartphone |
|   10 | iPHONE 5 32 MB         | Apple      |        150 |       2000 | Smartphone |
|   11 | Core 2 Duo 8 GB        | DELL       |        100 |       2500 | Notebook   |
|   12 | Playstation 4          | Sony       |        250 |       2500 | Console    |
|   13 | Notebook               | DELL       |        200 |       3000 | Notebook   |
|   14 | Ultrabook              | DELL       |        100 |       5500 | Ultrabook  |
|   15 | S9                     | SAMSUNG    |        300 |       2500 | Smartphone |
+------+------------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
15 rows in set (0.05 sec)

mysql> select * from vendas;
+---------+------------+----------------+-----------+----------+----------+
| IDVenda | Data       | Cliente        | IDProduto | QtdVenda | Desconto |
+---------+------------+----------------+-----------+----------+----------+
|       1 | 2017-07-08 | Carlos Santana |        15 |       10 |       50 |
|       2 | 2017-07-09 | Ana Maria Melo |         7 |        1 |      100 |
|       3 | 2017-07-09 | Fernando Silva |         8 |        1 |       70 |
|       4 | 2017-07-09 | Fernando Souza |        13 |        2 |      150 |
|       5 | 2017-07-10 | Luis Gama      |         3 |        1 |       50 |
|       6 | 2017-07-10 | Arthur Filho   |         7 |        2 |      100 |
|       7 | 2017-07-10 | Fernando Silva |        12 |        1 |       50 |
|       8 | 2017-07-10 | Fernando Souza |        15 |        3 |      200 |
|       9 | 2017-07-12 | Ana Maria Melo |         1 |        3 |      200 |
|      10 | 2017-07-13 | Cassio Moreira |         5 |        1 |       50 |
+---------+------------+----------------+-----------+----------+----------+
10 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Minha dúvida está na parte em que o enunciado pede para listar os produtos ainda não envolvidos em nenhuma venda.

Comment: Consegui com esse código mostrar os produtos envolvidos em transações:   select distinct idproduto from vendas, produtos where id = idproduto group by idproduto.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM produtos p LEFT JOIN vendas v ON  p.id = v.idproduto WHERE v.idproduto IS NULL;` - Ou seja "Retorne todos da ESQUERDA relacionando pelo idproduto, onde não houver idproduto".

Comment: Reverti sua edição, pq o campo da pergunta deve conter só a pergunta, Duas coisas: (1) se quiser, pode postar como resposta no campo de baixo, basta deixar um recado aqui que eu reabro temporariamente o post para isso. (2) perceba que é muito mais complicado o que vc fez em termos de performance e consumo de memória do que o JOIN. O JOIN faz comparação simples, sua solução obriga a  guardar todos os IDs pra depois comparar um a um gerando um número de comparações que equivale ao numero de linhas de um lado multiplicado pelo número de linhas do outro, o que é péssimo nesse cenário.